# How to model a repeated measure logistic regression in r

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I am currently trying to come up with a statistical model for my hypothesis. In my experiment there are two conditions (listen/describing). Each condition takes place for 20 seconds per trial. There are 50 trials in total. So we have 20 seconds listening -> 20 seconds generating -> 5 seconds break and repeat that 50 times.
In each trial we measure gaze coordinates (x and y) with an eye tracker. Now I want to set up a model that can predict the condition(listen/describing) based on the two gaze predictors (gaze x and gaze y). So

y(listen/describing) = ß0+ß1*gaze(x|y).

Now I assume that there must be a hierachical structure in the data, as in the repeated gaze measures (level 1) are nested within the participants (level 2). Also because I assume that every person has a "unique" gaze behavior. But this is exactly the part where I am stuck.

I know that I should set up a "Null-Model" in R without any predictor to test for the ICC. But how do I specify that in R?

`M0 <- glmer(formula = condition ~ 1 + (1 |id),data=gaze,family="binomial")`

`icc <-M0@theta[1]^2/ (M0@theta[1]^2 + (pi^2/3))`

I am not sure if this is actually correct, because I just dont understand how the variance will be estimated based on two categorical variables (condition(listen/describing) and id(1 to 19)). Can some one please help with this?

Mainly my confusion is based on me not understanding, if my gaze coordinates is nested in the time variable (each sample is associated with a timestamp in nanoseconds) or within the participant id.

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Best wishes